# JMSSerializer Bundle - Circular Reference Error (Only on Prod Azure Environment) - Symfony4/Doctrine2 REST API

Tags: api, doctrine-orm, symfony4, jmsserializerbundle

So I know somewhat similar issues have been discussed numerous times before but I haven't had any luck finding a solution with this specific issue.

Running locally (using MAMP) I have no issues with my API responses. However once deployed to the production Azure server (via Ansible) I run into the dreaded error:

`request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\CircularReferenceException: "A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class  "App\ServiceProviderBundle\Entity\Plan`

I'm confident that all of my doctrine associations are setup correctly yet something is triggering an infinite loop.

Here is a simplified entity relationship and the main associations from within my doctrine classes.

Any comments or help would be greatly suggested - many thanks!

Plan -> (hasMany) Bundle -> (hasMany) -> Product

```
class Plan {

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\ServiceProviderBundle\Entity\Bundle", mappedBy="plan")
 */
    private $bundles;
}


class Bundle {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\ServiceProviderBundle\Entity\Plan", inversedBy="bundles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $plan;

    /**
     * @SerializedName("products")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\ServiceProviderBundle\Entity\BundleProduct", mappedBy="bundle",
     *     cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $bundleProducts;
}


class BundleProduct {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\ServiceProviderBundle\Entity\Bundle", inversedBy="bundleProducts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $bundle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Exclude` annotation like that:

```
class BundleProduct {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\ServiceProviderBundle\Entity\Bundle", inversedBy="bundleProducts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Exclude
     */
    private $bundle;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nikita thanks for getting back to me. I have been Excluding everything by default and using @Expose to add the properties that I need.

I think I've found the issue - The JMSSerializerBundle wasn't enabled for the 'prod' environment. I'll know in about 5 minutes once the VM has spun up...